# Excel: How to find highest value in range based on adjacent cells with the same value

Tags: excel-formula

I have a column A with names (with duplicates), column B with language codes, and column C with numeral values.
I am struggling to make a formula that would find the highest value in column C, but only for those rows that have the same name – and return the value of column B for the row with that highest value for each unique name in column A. The output should be in another columns, like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:
`=INDEX($B:$B,MAX(IF(($C:$C=MAXIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$E2))*($A:$A=$E2),ROW($C:$C),"")))`
Enter the formula in cell `F2` with `ctrl + shift + enter` since it's an array-formula.

I search for the maximum value in column C if the value in column A equals the value in the cell in column E on the same row.
Then I check whether each value in column C equals that maximum value and check whether the value in column A equals the value in column E. If both are true return the row numbers of these en search for the maximum value of these row numbers.
The outcome is the row number of the maximum value that equals the name you searched for.
Using index results in the position of that row number in the desired column (B).

If you're using office 365 you can type `=UNIQUE(A:A)` in cell `E2` to get the unique names listed (prior to adding the formula mentioned above in `F2`

Comment: Thanks! Could you explain how does `*` work in this context?

Comment: Or rather "if both are true" section of my explanation. You could in theory add a third condition to be true by adding another `*(argument3)` after `($A:$A=$E2)`

Comment: Did you change the range to fit the actual range you're using?